# Problems removing a class from tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few div box that looks like this, they all are like `productholder2`, `productholder3` etc. This is one of them:

```
 <div class="productholder1>  
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod   tempor incididunt</p>     
    <input type="button" value="Läs mer" class="button">                                               
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to remove this hidden class on the `<p>` tag by using jQuery.

Somehow I need to specify that it's the `productholder1`'s `<p>` class I want to remove so the text pops up since in the CSS I have `.hidden{display:none);` by removing the class the text should pop up.

I have tried this following jQuery that I made but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".button").click(function () {
           $('.productholder1').removeClass("hidden");
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: `<div class="productholder1>`   should be `<div class="productholder1">`

Comment: Lots of people here who didn't seem to read the question.

Comment: @Avar is each button supposed to unhide just the `<p>` element that's next to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hidden` class is is on the `<p>` element not the `<div>` element which is what you're currently selecting, so you would want to use a selector of `'.productholder1 p'` to grab it and remove the class. If you only want `<p>` elements *immediately* below the product holder div, you can use this selector `'.productholder1 > p'` as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".button").click(function () {
           $('.productholder1 p').removeClass("hidden");
       });
   });
</script>
```

Some other options -

1. All `<p>` elements with a `hidden` class immediately below a `<div>`

   1. `$('div > p.hidden')`
2. Multiple selectors with a `<p>` below

   1. `$('.productholder1 p, .productholder2 p, .productholder3 p')`

Comment: ***"I have few div box that looks like this, they all are like productholder2, productholder3 etc."***

Comment: You need some type of unique identifier for the selector, but you could use `$('div>p.hidden').removeClass('hidden')` to grab all of them, otherwise you will need to specify each `productHolderX` class.

Answer (score 3):

The `hidden` class is on a *child* of `.productholder1`, not on the element itself.  It's also a *sibling* of the button.

This line will remove that class from any (descendent) element of `.productholder1` that has that class.  For efficiency, it'll completely ignore any element that isn't already hidden:

```
$('.productholder1 .hidden').removeClass('hidden');
```

**However** - I think your plan was that each button only affects the elements that are in the same group?  If so, use this instead, which relies on just traversing the DOM hierarchy rather than there being a particular class on each group.

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

This one chunk of code will then work for *every* group of elements, without you having to duplicate it for each class `.productholderNNN`.

FWIW, using numbered classes to represent the individual members of groups of otherwise identical DOM structures is actually a mis-use of CSS classes.  That's what IDs are for.  Classes are supposed to represent groups of elements that should be treated identically.

Comment: please explain the downvote.  AFAICS this is the most correct answer here.

Answer (score 2):

its should like

```
  $('.productholder1').find("p").removeClass("hidden");
```

or

```
$('.productholder1 p').removeClass("hidden");
```

what you are trying to do is removing the class in  `.productholder1`  but the classs hidden is not there so you need to select the `.productholder1` to grab it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $(".button").click(function () {
                   $('.productholder1 p').removeClass("hidden");
               });
           });
        </script>
```

or

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {
                   $(".button").click(function () {
                       $('.productholder1').find('p').removeClass("hidden");
                   });
               });
            </script>
```